# jquery tooltipster plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltipster

I'm a newbie to jquery and this question is more so related to javascript than jquery. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using [Tooltipster Plugin](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) to create a tooltip everytime i hover over a `<td>` element in a datatable. To do so, i have looped over each row in the datatable and then selected the `<td>` element using childnode, and applied the .tooltipster() function. However, the tooltip works only for the 1st row `<td>` element. Any idea how to get it working for all rows ?

```
 $('#mytable tbody tr').each(function(){
     //childNode[7] is the <td> element on which i want the tooltip
     $(this.childNodes[7]).tooltipster({    
            animation: 'fade',
            delay: 200,
            theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
            trigger: 'hover',
            interactive: 'true',
            functionBefore : function drawChart() {
  // This isnt needed to understand the problem so i have not pasted the code
}

});
});
```

Table data

```
 <td class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#chart_div"  style="padding-left:40px" id="storage" >
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/database.png")" />   
 </td>
```

Comment: If you just neeed a small text as tooltip, then use "title" instead of tooltip, that will be more easy and simple.

Comment: Why did you ask this question again? I answered on the other one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion for you.

If you just need to show a text as tool-tip for your elements, then simply use title.

Usage of title is simple.

For example,

**HTML**

```
<div title="your tooltip here">The content of the document......</div>
```

**screenshot**

[image: sample screenshot]

This will be a simple step to solve your issue.